# Output kivy audio on linux

Tags: python, audio, kivy

```
    def another(self, instance):
    sound = SoundLoader.load("123.mp3")
    if sound:
        sound.play(self)
```

Output:

```
[CRITICAL] [AudioSDL2   ] Unable to initialize SDL: b''
[WARNING] [Audio       ] Unable to find a loader for
```

I have Manjaro linux, help pls